# Change in the sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Wondering what the piece of code I can use to change the look of my sidebar for example how "categories" "tag clouds" and so put themselves in boxes? Right now many of them flush with the box (right), has been the center but it was not pretty. Does not own any idea what it might be to change, it is in the style sheet or in the sidebar for example?

Using this theme: http://wp-themes.com/colors/?TB_iframe=true

have tested with padding like this: 
.widget
{
    margin-bottom:12px;
    padding: 5px;
}

but without success.

Suggestions on how I can fix this? I am a noob in this is also not very good at English but give it a try anyway. ;)

Style.css

```
     Sidebar Styles
====================================================================================================  ========================================
*/
#sidebarLayout {width:228px; float:left; margin-left:15px; margin-top:1px;}
.widget { margin-bottom:12px;}
.wdTitle {height:38px; width:228px; background:url(layout/wdTitleBg.png);}
.wdTitle h2 {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; line-height:34px; margin-left:15px;}
.wdContent {background:#e1e5e7; width:227px; margin-left:1px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-top:3px;
line-hight:100%;}
.wdContent li:hover {no-repeat;}
.wdContent li {line-height:15px; height:35px; padding-left:25px; margin:1.5px 0px;}
.wdContent ul li ul { display:none; }
.wdFooter {height:4px; background:url(layout/wdFooterBg.png); width:227px; margin-left:1px;}
.wicon {width:34px; height:24px; background:url(layout/widgetIcon.png) no-repeat; float:left; margin-right:2px;}
/* 

Sidebar.php:

    <div id="sidebarLayout">

<div class="widget">
 <div class="wdTitle">
  <h2>Sök?</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="wdContent">
  <div class="icon" id="searchIcon"></div>
   <?php get_search_form(); ?>
  </div>
 <div class="wdFooter"><!-- .wdFooter for design only --></div>
</div>

<!-- <?php if ( function_exists('wp_tag_cloud') ) : ?>
<div class="widget">
 <div class="wdTitle">
  <h2>Etikettmoln</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="wdContent">
  <div>
   <div id="etikettmoln">
    <?php $tags = wp_tag_cloud('orderby=count&order=RAND'); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wdFooter"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?> -->

 <?php if(!function_exists("dynamic_sidebar") || ! dynamic_sidebar('sidebar')) : ?><?php endif;?>
</div>
```

I use Wordpress for those of you who did not understand it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't yet understand what your exact question is.

Comment: Look at my sidebar on b3tty.com. Category list, tag cloud etc. licking the left edge of the boxes.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean, seems fine to me in FF 3.6

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com for Wordpress-specific advice.

Comment: Change the dimensions of the categories, tag clouds, archives, etc. as interfering in boxes i have in my sidebar. Now the visit statistics, social media icons and links to good but I want everyone to fold the same way, and not flush with the edge of the boxes as they do now. I have tested with a variant of padding without success.

Answer (score 0):

To change what your theme looks like, you must modify the style.css file in the theme's directory.

I would add

.wdContent > div { padding: 5px;}

to the style.css file in your theme directory and it will put a 5px border round your cloud.

You might also find the line that reads

.wdContent {background:#e1e5e7; width:227px; margin-left:1px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-top:3px;
line-hight:100%;}

and change the padding-bottom to 3px like the padding-top

I my view those changes will improve things a bit.

Comment: Thanks!
I have made these changes. The only thing that made any difference was when I changed "padding-bottom: 30px" to 3 and it became a bit too much so everything seemed to not be boxed in so I put in 10px instead and it was really neat. However, I still have this problem with the tag cloud, categories and subjects that edge completely licked the boxes to the left.